# False or null for error checking -Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering which of the two is appropriate:

`error = null` or `error = false`

```
if(error) {
 //handle it
}
```

Is it a matter of preference/coding style or does one have an actual advantage over the other. Is it contextual? Is there a consensus at all on the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statements evaluate to `false`.

`var error = false;` will be appropriate if you only want to know about error or not. If some cases, you may want to have error message in the `error`, then you can assign to `null`.

Both are valid. The choice is based on purpose of `error` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Both the examples you have given will evaluate to false.

In this simplistic example you have given there is no difference - both `null` and `false` will trigger the conditional expression.

Answer (score 1):

---

Let me try again.

```
error = null;
if (!error === true) {
    // this will work
};
if (error === false) {
    // this will not work
};
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/QrbmS/) you can test in.

Comment: I was playing with a JS fiddle and it didn't reflect this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the error variable as a string, then you can add messages to help debugging, telling the developer where the problem occured.